# Diagonalisation of quasi-thermal state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-information, density-operator, coherent-states

I have the following density operator $$\frac{1}{t \pi N} \int_{\mathbb{C}} \mathrm{d}^2\gamma \exp
\left[
-\frac{|\gamma+r\alpha|^2}{t^2 N}
\right]
|{\gamma}\rangle\langle{\gamma}|,$$
where $0\leq t,r\leq 1$ are fixed, and $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is also a constant. The integral runs over coherent states, and $\mathrm{d}^2\gamma := \mathrm{d}\Re(\gamma)\mathrm{d}\Im(\gamma)$ (where both real and imaginary parts run from $-\infty$  to $+\infty$ to span the whole of $\mathbb{C}$).

I would like to find the eigenstates of this operator. Although it is already diagonal, I am having trouble identifying the eigensolutions. I hope this is a very silly question and get a quick reply!

Comment: Isn't this diagonal in the gamma basis already?

Comment: @PratikRath. Coherent states are not orthogonal, so they do not compose a basis (although they are complete).